# Insert in two related table at once with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have two entities like

```
   public class Person
        {
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int DataId { get; set; }
    }
     public class Data
        {
                public int DataId { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
        public int PersnId{ get; set; }
}
```

as you see both table are relate to each other. I want a solution to insert data in both table at once. I 1-insert person, 2-insert data and then update person and it works but I'm  looking for way to eliminate Update. 
My mapping for person table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="TestNhibrinate" assembly="TestNhibrinate">
    <class name="TestNhibrinate.Entites.Person" table="Person" lazy="false">
        <id name="PersonId" column="PersonId" type="int" >
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="50" />
        <many-to-one name="Adress" class="TestNhibrinate.Entites.Adress" column="AdressId"/>        
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and same mapping for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You entities should look like this:

```
       public class Person
            {
             public Person()
             {
                DataCollection = new List<Data>();
             }
                public int PersonId { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int DataId { get; set; }
                public IList<Data> DataCollection{get;set;}

                public void AddData(Data item)
                {
                   if(!DataCollection.Contains(item))
                   {
                      DataCollection.Add(item);
                   }
                }
        }
         public class Data
            {
                    public int DataId { get; set; }
            public string details { get; set; }
            public Person Person{ get; set; }
    }
```

This way you create a one-to-many relation from Person to Data. If you save your person entity after you added some data, the data will also be persisted. This depends on your cascade options offcourse.

I'm not sure how to map this with XML mappings, since i always use Fluent or Auto mappings.